# How to use video as a background in Android

Tags: android

I currently developing a small app in android right now, and instead of using an image resource, I wanna use video as the background. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use layout with videoview as background

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<VideoView  
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"

         />
```